# Export centroids to use for creating a bivariate map

Tags: r, gis

First post!

So, for a research project, I want to create circles around centroids of different world countries. I tried to export centroid data from MapWindow5 like so: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZgrUNPoZHs&t=431s&ab_channel=BurkeyAcademy

However, the program seems different from 10 years ago and a lot of functionalities aren't available anymore.

Could anyone help me with this? I just want to use an R package to access a world map and create a data frame with long and lat coordinates that represent the centroids of different countries (not the centers!).

Thank you in advance!

I tried extracting centroids through mapwindow5, following the youtube video, however, the amount of Plugin-options seem to have slimmed down. I can put the centroids on the map, but I cannot seem to export the coordinates!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The package `CoordinateCleaner` contains a data.frame called `countryref` with, among other things, the centroids of countries. It appears to come from multiple sources and so has multiple entries for some countries that sometimes disagree with each other.